# TextView integer numbers as drawable png

Tags: java, android, textview, drawable

I would like to make `TextView` counter with my own graphic numbers. How can I do this? Example: integer number will be `14356`, so I would like to show this number in `TextView` as a `Drawable`:

```
number1.png + number4.png + number3.png + number5.png + number6.png
```

Can somebody help me with some hint/tips how to code it? I don't need code, just some tips, or hints. I would like to code myself, just don't know how to start this problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: U want to show an image on a text! Why? U need to use Imageview!

Comment: i want show integer amount as imageview, i wrote wrong with TextView.... sorry

Answer (score 2):

Create a layout file with a `LinearLayout` and a few `ImageViews` in it:

```xml
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal" ...>
    <ImageView id="@+id/digit_1000" .../>
    <ImageView id="@+id/digit_100" .../>
    <ImageView id="@+id/digit_10" .../>
    <ImageView id="@+id/digit_1" .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use as many `ImageView` as needed. Then when you update the number, you can do something like this:

```
private int[] digitDrawables = {R.drawable.digit_0, R.drawable.digit_1, ...}
private ImageView[] digitViews;

private void initialize() {
    // Get image views from layout by ID.
    int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.digit_1, R.id.digit_10, R.id.digit_100, R.id.digit_1000};
    digitViews = new ImageView[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        digitViews[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
    }
}

private void updateNumber(int number) {
    String str = String.valueOf(number);
    // Go over each digit in string, updating the image views with:
    // -> digitViews[i].setImageResource(digitDrawables[digit]);
    // Hide the image views that you don't need with: 
    // -> digitViews[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

You can start from there.

Answer (score 1):

SO I would suggest doing this with Constraint Layout  [Horizontal Chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)(in packed Configuration) of Image Views.

In the code you can just update a counter within a loop with 1-sec delay if its count down timmer else do it the way you indent to(game points) and if conditions checking if the new number changes 10's place, 100's place ....100000's place and update accordingly.